# Increase execution time when opening table tree

Tags: sql-server

When I open table tree of SSMS, the system runs for for some seconds and then it gets Error

> lock requests time out period exceeded.

I know that the system is blocked by an ALTER INDEX query from ETL Process, but I can’t kill the Alter index query.

Therefore I want to ask you how to increase the execution time of opening table tree?

I mean: when I open table tree and if there is blocking alter index query, the system should wait for 2 minutes instead of some seconds to execute.
How can we change the setting?

Comment: Which SSMS version are you using? Maybe you just need to install [the latest one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), 18.2?

Comment: I have version 14.0.17285.0

Comment: The [latest one is 18.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017). It became a standalone application a few years back and one of the early improvements was about blocking in the UI

Comment: Hi, i have install the newest version but it still have the same problem